# Is there a way to get the email signature for IMAP emails using Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I had an webmail using the javamail framework, so I can read, edit, search and send emails, but I would like to know if there is a way to get my custom signature email from the email client (outlook/Gmail/yahoo,etc), for when I send a new email in my webmail, getting this signature at the end of the email.

Comment: Through IMAP, no.  This is a client feature, not a server feature.   You _may_ be able to get this information through their respective HTTP APIs. (Eg, the GMail API, or Microsoft EWS/EAS/Graph/Mail API)

Comment: Got it, thank's Max. in my case, as I can have any type of server email, and not all HTTP APIs have a way to get only the email signature, I think I'll create a custom email signature CRUD inside my webmail, to be send.